# Time zone varies when ruby version varies why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I am running Rails 3.0.1 with Ruby 1.9.2p290.In rails c

```
Time.zone
```

gives

```
 => (GMT+00:00) UTC
```

In my friends rails console [Rails 3.0.1, Ruby 1.8.7]

```
Time.zone
```

gives

```
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0xb75834fc @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @utc_offset=nil, @current_period=nil, @name="UTC">
```

Why different result for same code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just looks like the Ruby 1.9.2 class has a better `inspect` method. Have you tried comparing what classes are involved?

```
Time.zone
# => (GMT+00:00) UTC
Time.zone.class
# => ActiveSupport::TimeZone
```

The class is just a wrapper around the core Ruby class, so if 1.9.2 has a better TimeZone object then it will appear differently.